# Probability for fullhouse in POKER - 54 cards

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

I need to calculate the probability to get fullhuose in a poker game, using 54 cards - included 2 jokers.

I know that I have 13 kinds of cards, but I need 2 out of 4, then I have 12 kinds and I need 1 out of 4, and then I have 2 jokers but I need 1. (beside 3744 regular fullhouses).

My calculation:

$$13\binom{4}{2}\cdot12\binom42\cdot2=11,232$$

but I know that the right score is 5616.
where am I wrong?

Comment: This depends on the rules doesn't it? Presumably it is 5 card draw, before the draw? And jokers can be used as anything (this isn't typically the case in casinos)?

Comment: It seems you are choosing 6 cards.  How do you define a Fullhouse when including the jokers (besides 3 of a kind and 2 of the other)?  Does 3 of a kind, one of the other and one joker qualifies?  Does 2 + 2 + joker?

Comment: Im sorry, its supposed to be 13(4c2), my bad

Answer (score 2):

First, $$13\binom43\cdot12\binom42\cdot2=7488\;,$$ not $11,232$; $$13\binom43\cdot12\binom42\cdot3=11,232\;.$$

In fact there are $$13\binom43\cdot12\binom42=3744$$ full houses that do not use either joker. Now we’ll count the full houses that do include at least one joker.

If both jokers are present in a hand that does not contain a pair, the hand cannot be interpreted as a full house, and if both jokers are present in a hand that contains a pair, they’ll be used to make a four of a kind, which beats a full house; thus, we may assume that the hand contains just one joker.

If the hand also contains an ‘honest’ three of a kind, the joker will be used to make four of a kind, so we may assume that the hand consists of two pairs and a joker. There are $\binom{13}2$ ways to choose the denominations of the pairs, and for each of those denominations there are $\binom42$ ways to choose $2$ cards of that denomination. Finally, there are $2$ ways to choose the joker, so there are altogether

$$\binom{13}2\cdot\binom42^2\cdot2=5616$$

full houses of this type. Note that we do **not** want to multiply by another factor of $2$ to account for the fact that the joker could be combined with either of the pairs to make a three of a kind: it will always be combined the higher pair. The grand total is therefore

$$3744+5616=9360\;.$$

Comment: thank you.
I just dont understand the last part..
why (4c2) has power, and not multiply by 12 (there are 12 kinds of relevent cards left after we chose the dominant kind at the begining)

Comment: @bar: Do you mean the hands that use a joker to make the three of a kind?

Comment: yes, this part.

Comment: @bar: In order to use the joker to make a full house, the rest of the hand has to be two pairs. How many ways are there to make two pairs? First we choose which two denominations (like eight and ace, for instance) will be present; there are $\binom{13}2$ ways to make that choice. Then there are $\binom42$ ways to choose two cards of the smaller denomination and $\binom42$ ways to choose two cards of the larger denomination. Finally, we can choose either of the $2$ jokers. Total: $$\binom{13}2\cdot\binom42^2\cdot2\;.$$

Comment: Wouldn't the same logic you used to say that you can't have two jokers plus a pair and make a full house-that you have four of a kind-apply to three of a kind, a joker and another card?  Again you can make four of a kind.

Comment: @Ross: You’re right. Fixed; thanks!

Comment: Got it! but I still dont understand what is wrong with my way.
$$13*(4c2)*12(4c2)*2$$

Comment: @bar: You’re counting each hand twice. Suppose that the hand has two aces, two eights, and a joker. You’re counting it as three aces and two eights **and** as three eights and two aces, but of course it will actually be counted only as the former, since that’s the higher hand. I should add something about that to my answer.

Comment: @RossMillikan, I think I got it.. Thank you very much!